# preg_match_all pattern usage

Tags: php, regex

Hi i have a list of documents like this

```
1443 F 001.tif
1731 001.tif
1731 A 001.tif
1731 E 001.tif
1731 I 001.tif
ARELLANO GALVEZ 001.tif
AVILA 001.tif
berra morales jose 001.tif
berra morales jose 002.tif
CASTRO 001.tif
```

I want to catch the documents thats begin with a number and next have a LETTER and ends with another chars, later i want this matches in an array.

For example "1443 F 001.tif" have to match.

And i want the matches like

```
$encontrados[0] = 1443
$encontrados[1] = F
$encontrados[2] = 001.tiff

$pattern = '/^[\d]+[\w]?+(*)?/';
$var = preg_match_all($pattern, $documento, $encontrados);
```

But my Regex does not work, Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the pattern

```
'/^(\d+)\s*([a-zA-Z])\s*(.*)/'
```

for your task.

The `\d` will match your number (no need for square brackets here), `[a-zA-Z]` a letter (you can make it optional by writing `[a-zA-Z]?`) and `.*` matches the rest. Note that `\s*` eats any whitespace in between.

Comment: Wow, now i have a better knowledge about how regex work :D, this works really really nice

Comment: This really doesn't match the specification. You're regular expression would match things like `0103` or `2 _`.

Comment: @Jason I read the question that the letter is optional (as I clearly wrote in my answer). You are right that if the letter is obligatory the `?` has to be removed.

Comment: You have more wrong than just that, for example `\w` does not match just letters. Your regular expression *really* only ensures that the string starts with digits. The OP has already marked it as the answer, but I'm going to say **don't try this at home kids**.

Comment: I suppose if the OP doesn't require spaces, then this is better. But it's still a loose expression. It's best, when possible, to be as specific as you can. To be fair, the specification of the pattern is unclear.

Comment: @Jason You're right. Thats why I explain the parts within my answer (I don't think that I will always get all side-thoughts from the OP). As you can see from the other answer the OP is concerned about the spaces.

Comment: Hi :D nice update comments, maybe the clients put wrong names in the filenames, like a 3233A dsds.pdf sometimes have a space between first digits sometines not, but i believe that the regex in this example is ok, what do you think about?

Answer (score 2):

You're regular expression is malformed.

Try:

```
$pattern = '/^[\d]+ [a-zA-Z] .+$/';
```

**Note:** This pattern matches strings starting with digits, a space, followed by a letter (upper or lower case), a space, and ending with *any* other characters.

Comment: Hey :D thanks for your quick answer, but i have a problem with that that regex only make a one match a complete string, and does'nt work with strings that have a space between the first numbers and the Letter.